# Why is ~1 in an 8-bit byte equal to -2?

Tags: c#, math, binary

I would expect that a, due to a NOT 00000001 would turn into 11111110, otherwise known as 127, or -126 if counting the far left bit as the sign, if sign&magnitude was used.

Even in the instance of 2s compliment, I would expect the answer to result in -127

Why is it that the result is -2?

Comment: let me google the IEEE specs... but you're wrong: `-1`  is `1111 1111`, `-127` is `1000 0001`, `-128` is `1000 0000`.

Comment: 11111110 is unsigned 254, signed -2. The ~ operator performs a bitwise complement of each bit. 2s complement is a bitwise complement of bits then +1, so -0 = 0 (0000000 converts to (11111111 + 1) = 0)

Comment: Also note that the `byte` is converted to an `int`. Since a `byte` is unsigned it could never be negative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In two's complement:

```
-x = ~x + 1
```

By subtracting one from both sides we can see that:

```
~x = -x - 1
```

And so in your example, if we set `x = 1` we get:

```
~1 = -1 - 1 = -2
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider how the numbers wrap around.

If we start with `00000010` (2) and take away one then it is:

```
  00000010
- 00000001
 ---------
  00000001
```

Which is 1. We "borrow 1" from the column to the left just as we do with decimal subtraction, except that because it's binary `10 - 1` is `1` rather than `9`.

Take 1 away again and we of course get zero:

```
  00000001
- 00000001
 ---------
  00000000
```

Now, take 1 away from that, and we're borrowing 1 from the column to the left every time, and that borrowing wraps us around, so `0 - 1 = -1` is:

```
  00000000
- 00000001
-----------
  11111111
```

So `-1` is all-ones.

This is even easier to see in the other direction, in that `11111111` plus one must be `00000000` as it keeps carrying one until it is lost to the left, so if x is `11111111` then it must be the case that `x + 1 == 0`, so it must be -1.

Take away another one and we have:

```
  11111111
- 00000001
  --------
  11111110
```

So `-2` is `1111110`, and of course `~1` means flipping every bit of `00000001`, which is also `11111110`. So `~1` must be `-2`.

Another factor to note here though is that arithmetic and complements in C# always converts up to `int` for anything smaller. For a `byte` the value `11111110` is `254`, but because `~` casts up to `int` first you get `-2` rather than 254.

```
byte b = 1;
var i = ~b; // i is an int, and is -2
b = unchecked((byte)~b); // Forced back into a byte, now is 254
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a negative 2-compliment number to its decimal representation we have to:

- start scanning the bitstring from right to left, until the first '1' is encountered
- start inverting every bit to the left of that first '1'

Thus, in `11111110` we see the sign bit is `1` (negative number), and above method yields the number `000000010`, which is a decimal 2. In total, we thus get `-2`.